# What is the formal way to hide fields from the buit-in New and edit forms using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, form

I am facing some problems in hiding fields from the New and edit forms, if I chose to do so from the Content Type settings and set the column as hidden. As there seems to be some scenarios where these settings will get overridden, such as changing the default value of the hidden field.

So I am now trying to hide columns using jQuery instead, but I am asking what is the best approach to hide columns using jQuery? For example inside my issue tracking's New Form i got a column named "Item number" which I want to hide , so how I can hide it using jQuery ?

The related mark up is :-

```
<table width="100%" class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="113" class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">

<nobr>Item Number</nobr>

</h3></td>


<td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">

<span dir="none"><input title="Item Number" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" id="_x0049_D1_806a702b-1716-47f5-a93c-16067f502daf_$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""><br></span>

<span class="ms-metadata">Do not customize at the list level</span>


</td></tr></tbody>
```

So how I can hide this field? Also I have another form used inside my calendar list and seems there are columns that can not be hidden from the content type such as the All day event check box, so I am thinking of using JavaScript to hide them.

Edit2:-

here is a screenshot when i entered "item number" in the Description field:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the fields by:

```
 $('nobr:contains("Item Number")').closest('tr').hide();
```

Comment: this worked well ...

Comment: but how i can force the selector to be inside the table with .ms-formtable class just to avoid removing other markups..

Comment: You can do something like  `$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Item Number")').closest('tr').hide();`

Comment: but now let say i entered inside the Description field a text such as "Item number" will this cause the script to hide the Description row also ?

Comment: Definitely not. It looks for `<nobr>` tag and if it contains "Item Number", then it hides the closest `tr`

Comment: ok now i tried the following script :- $( document ).ready(function() {
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("All day Event")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Item Number")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("customer Initials")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Recurrence")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Workspace")').closest('tr').hide();




});
It was able to hide all the fields except a field named "All Day Event" ,, do u know what could cause this,, although it is rendered exactly inside the same markups.

Comment: Is it inside the .ms-formtable class?

Comment: yes exaclty the same as the other fields it is one of the TR inside the same table and the "All Event Day" is inside a nobr !! so strange .. now if using the F12 tool i add style=display:none the tr will be removed ,, but not sure the script did not work on this ..

Comment: That's weird. Try removing all the code and just try to hide All Day Event only. See if it works.

Comment: did not work ,,, very strange it is exactly the same as the other fields why it could not be hidden..

Comment: ok i remove the script add it again it worked ,, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Good to hear!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try below script which will hide the table

```
jQuery('input [title="Item Number"]').closest('table').hide();
```

If you want to hide on `input` box then use

```
jQuery('input [title="Item Number"]').hide();
```

**Update**

```
jQuery('input [title="Item Number"]').closest('tr').hide();
```

**Update2**

```
        $('.ms-formtable tr').each(function () { 
            $(this).find('td').each(function () { 
                var str_text = $(this).html(); 
                if (str_text.indexOf('Item Number') > -1) { 
                    $(this).closest('tr').hide(); 
                } 
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: But i do not want to hide the whole table i just need to hide the related TR which contain the field title and the input field, Second question is there is a more formal approach to use jQuery to hide columns, because what if i rename the field from Item Number to Item No , then in this case the script will not longer works,, while if i hide the column from the content type setting renaming the column will not affect any thing... so does SP provides a formal way to use jquery to do functions such as hide/show column, set defualt values , etc..

Comment: i though i can write a javaScript in a similar way as we write power shell scripts,, where we use strongly typed variables and object..

Comment: In that case you should look into Client Side Rendering using JSLinks

Comment: ok now i edited the New form and i add a scriot at the end of the form as follow:- <script>
$('input [title="Item Number"]').closest('tr').hide();
</script> but this did not hide any thing...and there is not any errors raised from the script... one final note is that i am adding the scripts to the built-in New forms ...could this be the reason ?

Comment: ok here is my updated script now <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('input [title="Item Number"]').closest('tr').hide();
});
</script> but still nothing will be hidden ? can you advice on this please?

Comment: i tried the following script :-<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

                             
    $('.ms-formtable table').each(function () {
    $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
               var str_text = $(this).find('td nobr').text();
               // console.log(str_text);
               if (str_text == 'Item Number') {
               $(this).hide();    
               } 
        
    });

});   

});
</script> but it did not hide any thing,, can u adivce ?

Comment: I would suggest you place with browser console tool and get the selector corrected. I coded based on the html you posted in your question.

Comment: yes i think i am using the correct selectors , i am searching for a table with .ms-formtable class, then i am looping through its Tr, then for each tr i am looping through its td nobr and select the text,, check it is the text i want to find then i am hidding the nearest tr ...

Comment: i tried your update but did not hide any thing ,, i am 100% confused i have a table with .ms-formtable class, inside the table i have tbody that have a tr inside the tr there is td ,,, why the script is not working,, could this be that i am using buit-in New form where the markup is being build at run time ...... as i i edit the New.aspx form from sharepoint i will not find the markup that is being rendered in the browser...

Comment: i provide the rendered html from the browser ,,, this what i did. i right click on the web page , click on view source ...

Comment: could we missed selecting the nobr as it contain the "Item Number" text? what do u think ?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: ok it worked well, but now i add the script to the edit form also, and inside the Description fields i entered the word "Item Number".. i thought that the script will hide the whole description field since it will contain "Item number" inside it but it did not ,, can u advice ? although this what i want , but can not understand why the script did not hide the description field also..

Comment: Can you check html in edit form? It seems description is outside TR in edit form.

Comment: no it will be inside a TR , can you check my Edit2 i provided the rendered markup ,, strange why the script did not hide the Description field also ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SP 2013, you can use Client Side Rendering to override how the fields are rendered in the new and edit form, and hide them that way.

I have not personally done this (yet), but I know it is a mechanism that is available for customizing forms in 2013.

Here is an article that goes in to [CSR for list forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms), and here is one that specifically addresses [hiding controls](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-a52cf8a7).

Because CSR is how SharePoint itself is rendering the forms, and by using this method you are literally overriding the default rendering code, I would say that this is the "formal" way of manipulating forms with Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom list forms for NewForm.aspx/EditForm.aspx

[Check here](http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/295973/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-List-Forms-Using-SharePoint-Designer-2010) you can remove the fields which you don't want to display

Only drawback of this implementation is that if you add new column to list you will have to manually add the field to it again or recreate the form

Comment: yes i know about using custom forms ,, but i do not want to go with this approach as it have some drawbacks i do not want to have,, since in my case i have a site templete and i will be creating many sub sites,,so i do not want to face a problem of modifying all the sub sites forms just becuase we decide to add a new column !!